# Cannot SSH after increasing open files limit to 2000000 - fedora core 26

Tags: ssh

Today I changed the limits of open files by editing:

- `/etc/sysctl.conf` :   `fs.file-max = 2000000`
- `/etc/security/limits.conf` : `* - nofile 2000000`

The value was changed to 2000000.

After a reboot, I am unable to login using ssh, as it dies giving the error:

> Event Log: Server sent command exit status 254

I'm trying `putty` to login to my server but no luck.

Any suggestions on getting in via ssh is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any kind of out-of-band access?  IE can  you login to a console and go undo your change?

Comment: hi zoredache. thanks for looking.   i  just  fixed  this using the linode rescue help guide. 
 https://linode.com/docs/troubleshooting/rescue-and-rebuild/